# Is "the bar", as in the bar that barristers work at as lawyers, capitalised or not?

Tags: capitalization

I'm applying for lawyer jobs and training, so I have to use the word "bar" a lot, and I've noticed that small and upper case B is used. I'm afraid my English isn't good enough to work out why. I know that "mechanical engineer" is lower-case and the job title "Mechanical Engineer" is upper-case, but for Bar vs bar I am confused.

Some examples I've found:

- Wikipedia refers to "[the bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_(law)#:%7E:text=In%20law%2C%20the%20bar%20is,a%20trial%20such%20as%20lawyers)".
- The Bar Council refers to "[the Bar](https://www.barcouncil.org.uk/about/about-the-bar.html)" throughout its pages
- An example chambers using upper-case "[Bar](https://bankhousechambers.co.uk/barrister/david-mason/)"
- An example law newspaper using lower case "[bar](https://www.lawgazette.co.uk/commentary-and-opinion/flexible-working-and-the-bar/5051360.article)"

So what are the rules for **Bar** vs **bar**?

Comment: Depending on context, the word bar is either a noun or a Proper Noun.  The noun usages are obvious.  The Proper Noun is when it refers to an implied specific organization such as the Wyoming Bar Association or American Bar Association, which can be referred to in shorthand as the Bar.

Comment: 'Bar' is a proper noun?

Comment: @Ram Pillai Certainly, if they serve Real Ale. // Seriously, as EDL says, if some appellation like 'Her Majesty's Government' is shortened, it retains the capital: 'the Government'. But there are also common-noun usages.

Comment: @EDL, actually American Bar Association is not the Bar. A lawyer's membership in the relevant Bar is generally required for practising the law (or for practising it as a barrister, in the jurisdictions that have that as a distinct status); a membership in a bar **association**, such as the American Bar Association, or analogous regional associations, is usually optional. (All this is, however, not crucial to answering the question.)